# How do I get the ID of a particular class using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have some div elements having class name `hover`, these div elements have parent divs having class name `hoverparent` but the id's of these parent elements are different.

Is it possible to get the ID of respective `.hoverparent` element while hovering on my `.hover` div elements?

I tried to get this by:

```
$('.hoverparent').attr('id')
```

But it gives the same first parent id every time.

Structure is like:

```
<div class="hoverparent" id="hover-1">
<div class="hover">ABC</div>
</div>
<div class="hoverparent" id="hover-2">
<div class="hover">DEF</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) or [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) functions to traverse up the DOM tree to find the "parent" element you are looking for:

```
$(".hover").hover(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).closest(".hoverparent");
    alert($parent.attr("id"));
});
```

The difference between `parent` and `closest` is that the first will only work if the `.hoverparent` element is the *immediate parent* of the `.hover` element; `closest` will  search upwards through *all* ancestors to find it.

Answer (score 1):

try $(this).parent().attr('id') , in your hover callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hover').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).parent().attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

don't call your class hover. this should work

```
$(".hover").hover(
  function () {
   var id =  $(this).parent().attr('id');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add each loop like this :

```
$(".hoverparent").each(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the parent method in the handler for the hover event:

```
$('.hover').hover(function(evt){
    var par = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    //Now do with ID what you need
},
function(evt){
    //presumably you don't need anything for mouseout
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method.
Like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var parentId = $(this).parent('div.hoverparent').attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".hover").hover(function(){

console.log($(this).closest(".hoverparent").attr("id"));
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9dJJ9/1/show/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('.hover').hover(function() {
    var parentID = $(this).parent().attr('id');    alert(parentID);
});
```